Swagger UI wrong CURL path
I got this url dev.internal/myapi/swagger/index.html where my Swagger UI it's served and works but everytime i try a request the curl generated for the request tries to call dev.internal/get instead of dev.internal/myapi/get.
I'm using dotnet 8
I tried to change app.UseSwaggerUI(); to
app.UseSwaggerUI( c => 
{
c.RoutePrefix = "myapi/swagger"
c.SwaggerEndpoint("/myapi/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My Cool API V1");
}

it didn't work instead just changed the link to access it from dev.internal/myapi/swagger/index.html to dev.internal/myapi/myapi/swagger/index.html  and the url generated by the request still failed.
What i should change to make it call myapi/get
EDIT:
To be precise swagger works it doesn't work the curl i link a screenshot to be clear.
screenshot
as you see in the screenshot the call should be dev.internal/myapi/api/v2/configuration/list?page=0 instead i got /myapi/ removed and it fails.

May I know if you have a chance to check the solution below? If you need further help, please let me know, have a nice day.

If you are using vs2022, you can modify the launchUrl in the launchSetting.json .


        builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My Cool API", Version = "v1" });
        });
        ...
        var app = builder.Build();

        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c => {
                c.RoutePrefix = "myapi/swagger"; 
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My Cool API V1"); 
            });
        }
        ...

Then it will open the swagger page normally.

If you want all the api append /myapi,  the least cost is to use [Route("myapi/[controller]")].


I tried this method but it didn't work it just made the url longer but the call inside the curl still failed

Hi @AngelAndresLoaizaGonzalez I really want help you check this issue. Could you spend some time to create a brand new sample for me? And tell me how to reproduce the issue and what is the expect behavior, and please don't forget to hide your sensitive information, many thanks
